# How to calculate variable importance of each class with R caret package?

Tags: r, r-caret

When I output the variable importance in the model (rf), I used codes below (`rfmodel_all` is my model).

```
importance(rfmodel_all[11][[1]])
varImp(rfmodel_all)
```

Although I got the results below, both values of variable importance in each class were different.
what did their values of each class means?

```
importance(rfmodel_all[11][[1]])

                        F1         F2         F3        F4       F5
 dem5m_field2   10.2504042  6.9464506  3.1169946 13.394995 17.52028

 ah             -2.5141337 -3.9860137  3.1314217 11.585716 13.33464

varImp(rfmodel_all)
```

rf variable importance,

variables are sorted by maximum importance across the classes

```
                    F1     F2     F3    F4     F5
 vd             72.436 98.173 54.284 91.48 100.00

 twi            10.412  8.235 22.369 92.55  82.67
```

please tell me some references written about this kind of explanation if you know.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The `varImp()` function basically uses the `importance()` function from `randomForest()` and scale them from 0-100 , and rearranges them as you have already noticed. To get the same result, you can just do `varImp(..,scale=FALSE)` , for example:

```
set.seed(111)
mdl = train(Species ~ .,data=iris,
trControl=trainControl(method="cv"),importance=TRUE)

importance(mdl$finalModel)[,1:3]
               setosa versicolor virginica
Sepal.Length  5.69594   6.452202  6.661104
Sepal.Width   4.46492   1.171534  4.245839
Petal.Length 22.52265  32.843039 27.864307
Petal.Width  22.11490  33.060450 31.897033

varImp(mdl,scale=FALSE)
rf variable importance

  variables are sorted by maximum importance across the classes
             setosa versicolor virginica
Petal.Width  22.115     33.060    31.897
Petal.Length 22.523     32.843    27.864
Sepal.Length  5.696      6.452     6.661
Sepal.Width   4.465      1.172     4.246
```

The importance scores are basically obtaining by permutation and recalculating the change in accuracy in OOB samples. See [random forest page](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#varimp). It is a rough measure of how useful the variable in predicting each class correctly.

Comment: Thank you for polite explaination. I understood what the importance displayed here indicates. By the way, I have one more question in relation to this. Some importance values shows a negative value, is this right?

Comment: yes it's possible. most likely the variable is not very useful in predicting the correct class

Comment: OK. I understand. I'll find out how the importance values calculates. Thank you.